# Finding all values in an excel document and adding them to an array with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

```
$strPath="Path To Spreadsheet.xlsx"   
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  
$objExcel.Visible=$false  
$WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath) 
$fname = "Facility Name"   
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item($fname)  
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn  
$Search = $Range.find("Switch")
```

I need to be able to find all instances of a string not just one.

I have an excel spreadsheet with IP information and in there, we have Switches ranging from one per workbook all the way up to 10, so what i need to do is be able to find all instances of the word "Switch" and add them to an array i can play with. So all i have to do is find all the values and add them to a simple array. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't really help at all.

Comment: There are many ways to do this but you are not showing any research effort into building a solution. Look for ways to import and excel sheet into a powershell object which should get you started. SO is not a code writing service. If you get some code and it is not working correctly or need help with it then the SO community is here to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with it and was able to figure out a pretty simple solution.

```
$i = 1
$Search = $Range.find("Switch")
while ($i -eq 1) {
if ($Search.value2 -like  '*sw*') {
$Search.value2
$Search = $Search.offset(1,0)}
else {$i = 0}
}
```